# django-templates: as_ul not working, ways around it?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

So say I have the following template:

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<ul>
{% for author in authors %}
{{ author.firstname.as_ul() }} 
{% endfor %}
</ul>   
</body>
</html>
```

and the following view:

```
def displayauthors(request):
authors =Author.objects.all()
return render(request, 'displayauthor.html',{'authors':authors})
```

My problem is `{{ author.firstname.as_ul() }}` doesn't work, is there a way I can still display author.firstname as a list item?

Thanks for helping a noob!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
  <ul>
  {% for author in authors %}
    <li>{{ author.firstname }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>   
  </body>
</html>
```

`.as_ul` is used when you have a django form object and you want to render the form elements as an `ul`.